# How default Web Page is loaded with just TCP connection and no HTTP transaction?

Tags: webserver, http, tcp, sniffing, packet

Below is the packet capture from WireShark when a web request is made to the Google Server

[image]

172.217.26.228 is the IP address of the Google Server.

[image]

Filter that I am using is

```
(ip.dst == 172.217.26.228) || (ip.src == 172.217.26.228 )
```

In the above packet capture, I see only the TCP transactions happening. I don't see any HTTP protocol message exchange.
Even then how is it possible for the Web Browser to show the Google's Home Page?

[image]

How did the WebBrowser got the data of Google's Home page?

Comment: I assume you get the same if you disconnect from the network?  The difference when you are connected to the network, at the top right of the page you get additional links and maybe your account info?  I assume this is just a built in/cached page to save bandwith/resources and for speed.  Developer Tools may also help you prove what's going on.

Comment: What tool and what pcap filters did you use while obtaining this capture? If you select e.g. packet 12703 or 12854 and open the details pane, what is shown under "IP Version 4 → Total Length"?

Comment: @grawity: I am using wireshark to capture packets. and pcap filter that i used is -
ip.dst == 172.217.26.228 || (ip.src == 172.217.26.228 )
Under packet 12703, total length is shown as 52
Under packet 12854, total length is shown as 40

Comment: @HelpingHand: No, when disconnected from the network will get "No internet" page.